# comment on cck fields possible?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-comments

Is it possible to implement comments on cck fields, because comments architecturally reference nodes with them right. Can I extend comments module to have on fields of a content type?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use comments for this, since they are hardwired, in the database, to a node, via node_id.

There might be other options, such as annotations and such that use their own database-tables and objects instead of commments. I am not aware of any good solution though.

Comment: I thought so, but I was wondering someway I could extend the comments.